# Configuring a K2 worklist to display and sort tasks by numerical date-time?

Tags: sorting, date, datetime, k2

My company is developing a workflow using K2 Blackpearl which employees will interact with using K2 worklists. 
I would like to sort their worklist tasks chronologically, with the oldest instances at the top. Sorting on the column 'Workflow Start Date' should solve the issue, except this column displays hh/mm for items <24 hours, days of the week  (which sort alphabetically?!) and dd/mm/yy for items >7 days old.
Obviously sorting three different data types produces a meaningless result.

Is there a way to have the 'Start Date' column display data in a single numerical format only?

Otherwise, is there a different way to achieve the desired workflow sorting?

Comment: Which worklist are your users using?  The one in the K2 workspace?

Comment: We've built a simple form using Designer, to which we've added the Worklist control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the (pretty new) Worklist control, there is an easy and flexible way to do that.

Users can modify the default filter (in your case, don´t filter out anything) and specify the sorting (that´s what you want).
Doing this, they can sort how they want and even change the order at any time if they change their mind.

If you want to set that 'by default' for new users, you can do that by editing the view, in the properties of the Worklist control, select **Filter** and modify the configuration.

I hope this helps.